# What is the difference between partition sort and quick sort?

Tags: sorting, quicksort

What is the difference between partition sort and quick sort?

Answer (score 8):

[Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is a Partitioning Sorting Algorithm, you might refer to [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) which also is a Partitioning Sorting Algorithm, the biggest difference is probably the speed, Quicksort is faster even though both of them are O(n*log(n)).

Quicksort uses a Pivot element for its sorting and MergeSort divides & conquers. Both however are in-place sorting algorithms, which means they don't use any extra memory when sorting.

Comment: +1 - Excellent Answer

When I saw "partition sort" I immediately thought the "he must mean a Mergesort if he's *contrasting* it to a QuickSort."

Comment: MergeSort is not an in place sorting algorithm: Merge Sort requires a copy of the array to execute the merge. From Wikipedia: _Merge sort's most common implementation does not sort in place_. There is an optimization where you only allocate an array of size N/2, but it's still not in place.

Also, while Quicksort is typically faster in practice, Mergesort has a theoretically tighter upper bound run time. Quicksort is O(n*2) in the worst case, not O(n*log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

There is a part of the algorithm QuickSort that is the partition, its about placing an element of the array between all the elements that are above him(on his right subarray) and below him(on his left).

Comment: +1 Good info.  keep in mind, with 'homework'-tagged questions, the goal is to provide guidance more than a specific answer.